# How to move the label to center

Tags: codenameone

I want to do the app when I press the tab button the result(website) will show at the center. Now the result is like this the result show at bellow:

[image]

But I want my result like this:
For example when I press home will show google website then when I press the video tab it will change to youtube website.
[image]

Here is my coding:

```
public void start() 
{
    if(current != null)
    {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    Form page = new Form("Apps", new BorderLayout());
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
    FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_BORDER_ALL, s);
    page.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", icon, (e) -> Log.p("Right"));


    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setURL("https://google.com");
    page.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);

    Tabs t = new Tabs();
    Style st = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
    FontImage home = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, st);
    FontImage dash = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MUSIC_VIDEO, st);
    FontImage cal = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SEARCH, st);

    t.addTab("Home", home, new Label("website 1"));
    t.addTab("Video", dash, new Label("website 2"));
    t.addTab("Search", cal, new Label("website 3"));

    page.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, t);
    page.show();
}
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using tabs without adding anything into them. `Tabs` replace the entire content of the screen which isn't the right thing for what you are trying to accomplish. You must have confused my comment in a different form where I referred to the bottom mode of the tabs container.

Instead of using tabs just use toggle buttons:

```
BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
browser.setURL("https://google.com");
page.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);

FontImage home = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, st);
FontImage dash = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MUSIC_VIDEO, st);
FontImage cal = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SEARCH, st);

ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
RadioButton home = RadioButton.createToggle("Home", bg);
home.setMaterialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME);
RadioButton dash = RadioButton.createToggle("Video", bg);
dash.setMaterialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_MUSIC_VIDEO);
RadioButton cal = RadioButton.createToggle("Search", bg);
cal.setMaterialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_SEARCH);

page.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, GridLayout.encloseIn(3, home, dash, cal));

dash.addActionListener(e -> browser.setURL("https://youtube.com/"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, If I want to change the button color and size. How to change it?

Comment: You can use the CSS or theme designer to customize the `ToggleButton` UIID or use `setUIID` on the buttons to change their style